# MPlayer Webcam on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, webcam, mplayer

I am trying to run [this demo](http://morepypy.blogspot.hk/2011/07/realtime-image-processing-in-python.html) and I need to capture video via MPlayer.  The sample script works if I load video via a file, but if I try and stream it live from my webcam, I get nothing.  I installed my MPlayer via Brew and if I do `mplayer tv://` I just get a green screen and the light on my webcam is not activated.

How do I capture video from my built-in webcam with MPlayer on a Macbook Pro 13 inch running OS X?